# Publicar app Windows Phone Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone, silverlight

Estou tentando publicar uma APP Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, porem estou sempre com o mesmo erro:

> O publicador no pacote carregado não coincide com o publicador
>   esperado. O publicador esperado para este aplicativo é:
>   "CN=6A1002ED-D5A1-49CA-A442-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

No arquivo WMAppManifest.xml eu já inclui o Meu nome no Author e o código da APP `CN=6A1002ED-D5A1-49CA-A442-XXXXXXXXXXXX` no campo Publisher, mesmo assim sempre recebo a mesma mensagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `WMAppManifest.xml`, na aba `Packaging`, o nome do author e o publisher precisam ser os mesmos que você cadastrou na Loja, ou seja, seu nome de desenvolvedor tem que estar nos campos `Author` e `Publisher`.

O product e publisher ID são alterados quando você faz o upload para a Loja.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer a sincronização antes de enviar para loja. No visual Studio você vai clica com botão direto em cima do nome do seu aplicativo na sua solução. Após isso é só Store >> Associate App with the Strore...

Ao fazer o seu login você terá os nomes dos seus apps separado. Escolhe o que você quer usar é sincronizar.

Ai é só correr para o abraço.

Comment: Não tem esta opção, pois a App e Silverlight a unica opção que tem no link Store é: Launch Windows App Certification kit.

Comment: Você colocou o mesmo nome de publicação na hora do cadastro, para ver seu nome de publicação é só ir em conta no site dev WP, lá vai ter o campo "Nome do publicador". Esse nome tem que estar igual se não vai dar erro. Se ainda não for isso. Não sei qual é o problema.